# Transforming (rotate) an Element programmatically in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, css-transforms

I am coding in the Angular framework. I need to rotate an element (div) (flip-card-inner) when a specific input (cvv) has been selected.

I can't use :focus as the input element is not a sibling or a child of the element I need to rotate.

Does this have to be done programmatically? Any help would be appreciated.

The grey card should rotate when the cvv input is selected
[image: the grey card should rotate when the cvv input is selected]

```
<div class="container">
  <p-card>
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img
            src="../../../../../assets/creditCard.svg"
            alt="Avatar"
            style="width: 50px; height: 50px; align-self: flex-end"
          />

          <p>{{ cardNumber }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>John Doe</h1>
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-container">
      <label for="cardnumber">card number</label>
      <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="cardNumber" />
    </div>

    <div class="input-container">
      <label for="cardholder">card holder</label>
      <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="cardHolder" />
    </div>

    <div class="expiry-container">
      <div class="input-expiry">
        <label for="month">month</label>
        <input style="width: 65px" type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="month" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-expiry">
        <label for="year">year</label>
        <input style="width: 65px" type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="year" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-expiry">
        <label for="cvv">cvv</label>
        <input
          class="cvv"
          style="width: 65px"
          type="text"
          pInputText
          [(ngModel)]="cvv"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </p-card>
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
    padding: 50px;
}

/* The flip card container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect */
.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 440px;
    height: 280px;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
  }
  
  /* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
  .flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  /* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
  /* .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  } */

 

  
  /* Position the front and back side */
  .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  /* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
  .flip-card-front {
    background-color: #bbb;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  
  /* Style the back side */
  .flip-card-back {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }


  .input-container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .expiry-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    
  }

  .input-expiry{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  input:focus  {
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a boolean property in your component (like **isCVVFocused**) and set it to **true** on [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) event and to **false** on [focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event).
Then you can use this property in template to conditionally add/remove a css class, which will apply rotation styles for elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [*directive*](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) at the `<input>` which gets triggered on `:focus`. This should add a CSS class to the card which makes it rotate. Afterwards, remove this class on *blur*:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[onFocus]',
})
export class OnFocusDirective {
    private el: ElementRef;
   
    constructor(private _el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {
        this.el = this._el;
    }

    @HostListener('focus', ['$event']) onFocus(e) {
        // set class
    }
    
    @HostListener('blur', ['$event']) onBlur(e) {
        // reset class
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in Angular. This is the stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yca7ia?file=src/app/app.component.css

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  OnInit,
  Renderer2,
  ViewChild
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  cardNumber;
  cardHolder;
  month;
  year;
  cvv;
  @ViewChild("cardImg", { static: false }) cardImg: ElementRef;
  constructor(private elem: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onCVVFocus() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.cardImg.nativeElement, "img-rotate");
  }

  onFocusOut() {
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.cardImg.nativeElement, "img-rotate");
  }
}
```

Added the below CSS:

```
.img-rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```